# arangodb single instance doing 3 tasks: agent, coordinator, primary db - as in cluster configuration

Tags: arangodb

I can run 3 instances of arangodb on one machine: agent, coordinator and primary db.
But they consume >200M + >200M + >100M of RAM = >500M.

I can run arangodb in "single instance mode" and it consumes > 300M only.
(If You have 1G of RAM then 200M is a lot.)

Is there a way to run one single instance that would act as " configured in cluster" ?

I mean on first machine I would run single instance that would do all 3 tasks: it would be agent0 for agency, coodrinator0 and primary db0 for cluster,

on second machine I would run single arangodb instance that would act as: agent1 for agency, coordinator1 and primary db1 for cluster,
and so on.

Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the system footprint for your development / testing environment, you can [use a shellscript to launch the cluster](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/scripts/startLocalCluster.sh), or even [run ArangoDB in a local mesospmere](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/README_maintainers.md#local-cluster-startup). You could run local test cluster with one node each. For production setups this is however not advised.

If you want to reduce the memory footprint, you could probably reduce the number of prepared V8 contexts with `--javascript.v8-contexts`.

You can also reduce the number of agency nodes, but you will loose warranties about data integrity in case of system failures then.